# Where can I see .atr files in OBIEE

Tags: obiee, bi-publisher

I am new to OBIEE. How do we see .atr files in OBIEE. There are some files in OBIEE with extension .atr.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to OBI and you're looking at .atr files you're doing something wrong. Several things actually:
1.) OBIEE is outdated and you should be on its replacement OAS - Oracle Analytics Server - since several years already
2.) You only ever touch .atr files when you know precisely, 100%, what you're doing, why you're doing it and how.
So the question becomes: what are you actually trying to achieve? What is your target, your functionality which you're after etc.
Because for any scenario or request you may have there are X things you can and should choose before looking at the .are files. Especially since....spoiler alert. There are no more .atr files if you move to a current and up to date version of Oracle Analytics.

Comment: When I unarchive these scorecards, only the high-level folders get modified for the 'last modified' attribute. Inside, subfiles aren't changing the 'last modified' attribute; they are only updating the 'last accessed' attribute. We are certain there are changes in the subfiles, but the 'last modified' attribute remains unaffected.

If this issue is related to permissions, what permissions are required for the subfiles to also have their 'last modified' attribute updated when changes occur?"

Comment: current permission is read and travers

Comment: but unarchive is succuss with content change but last attribute is not updating

Comment: The .atr files were standalone physical files on the file system back in outdated versions of OBIEE, yes. And you won't get that attribute updated. That wasn't done by the system. Take a step back from looking at files and look at "what am I trying to achieve" / "what is my goal". As stated your version is outdated. It doesn't receive patches or changes anymore. What you have is what you work with.

Comment: why only one folder (sample lite ) has the .atr files .why not others I have created 2 to 3 folders with dashboard and analysis and score cards .but I cant see them on file storage

Comment: Just to repeat and consolidate:
1.) Your version isn't the current one and badly outdated.
2.) The new versions handle the catalog differently: https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=44316555243064&parent=DOCUMENT&sourceId=2655137.1&id=2724149.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=gpvg4mus8_102
3.) Oracle Statement Of Direction for Oracle Scorecard & Strategy Management Product (OSSM) - Oracle Support Doc ID 2530313.1.

Comment: unfortunately, I don't have access to the oracle support account .is there any way can access the pages

Comment: And My requirement is 


1.) Can we see .atr files from UI (OBIEE) 11g  or other versions

2.)Scorecard and dashboard subfiles not updating the last modified attribute sometimes, but sometimes it is updating.

can you please share what might be the reason for sometimes updating and sometimes not?

Comment: You can create a normal account on support.oralce.com and read all those documents. No you can't see the files from the GU. Their content is being read and translated into the properties, permissions etc of objects at runtime. You're not supposed to touch the file ever. And the files get updated as decided by and required by the product. It's not a process you can or should try to influence.